# AlarmManager not fire notification even when app is completely destroy from memory

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am currently developing a task reminder app that allows users to specify the desired time, date, and day for receiving notifications along with an alarm. To illustrate, a user can input the following details:

```
Jul 7, 2023
Tuesday
11 : 30 AM
```

Now the the user should receive a notification, accompanied by an alarming sound, even if the app has been completely closed. I have attempted various approaches but haven't been successful so far. This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    private AlarmManager alarmManager;
    private String dateToNotify, timeToNotify;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        binding.dateEditText.setOnClickListener(this);
        binding.timeEditText.setOnClickListener(this);
        binding.setAlarmButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.date_edit_text)
            showMaterialDatePickerToUpdate();
        else if (v.getId() == R.id.time_edit_text)
            showMaterialTimePicker();
        else if (v.getId() == R.id.set_alarm_button) {
            String monthInAlphabets = dateToNotify.substring(0, 3);
            int monthInDigits = 0;
            if (monthInAlphabets.equalsIgnoreCase("Jan"))
                monthInDigits = 1;
            else if (monthInAlphabets.equalsIgnoreCase("Feb"))
                monthInDigits = 2;
            else if (monthInAlphabets.equalsIgnoreCase("Mar"))
                monthInDigits = 3;
            else if (monthInAlphabets.equalsIgnoreCase("Apr"))
                monthInDigits = 4;
            else if (monthInAlphabets.equalsIgnoreCase("May"))
                monthInDigits = 5;
            else if (monthInAlphabets.equalsIgnoreCase("Jun"))
                monthInDigits = 6;
            else if (monthInAlphabets.equalsIgnoreCase("Jul"))
                monthInDigits = 7;
            else if (monthInAlphabets.equalsIgnoreCase("Aug"))
                monthInDigits = 8;
            else if (monthInAlphabets.equalsIgnoreCase("Sep"))
                monthInDigits = 9;
            else if (monthInAlphabets.equalsIgnoreCase("Oct"))
                monthInDigits = 10;
            else if (monthInAlphabets.equalsIgnoreCase("Nov"))
                monthInDigits = 11;
            else if (monthInAlphabets.equalsIgnoreCase("Dec"))
                monthInDigits = 12;

            int dateOfMonth, year;
            if (dateToNotify.length() == 11) {
                dateOfMonth = Integer.parseInt(dateToNotify.substring(4, 5));
                year = Integer.parseInt(dateToNotify.substring(7, 11));
            } else {
                dateOfMonth = Integer.parseInt(dateToNotify.substring(4, 6));
                year = Integer.parseInt(dateToNotify.substring(8, 12));
            }

            String hours = timeToNotify.substring(0, 2);
            String minutes = timeToNotify.substring(5, 7);
            String ampm = timeToNotify.substring(8, 10);

            /*Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dateOfMonth);
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthInDigits);
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(hours));
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(minutes));
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            if (ampm.equalsIgnoreCase("AM"))
                calendar.set(Calendar.AM, 0);
            else
                calendar.set(Calendar.PM, 1);*/

            //            calendar.set(year, monthInDigits, dateOfMonth, Integer.parseInt(hours), Integer.parseInt(minutes));

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyAlarmReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(hours));
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(minutes));

            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

            /*if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
            } else {
                alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
            }*/
        }
    }

    private void showMaterialTimePicker() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        MaterialTimePicker.Builder builder = new MaterialTimePicker.Builder();
        builder.setTitleText("Select Time...");
        builder.setTimeFormat(TimeFormat.CLOCK_12H);
        builder.setInputMode(MaterialTimePicker.INPUT_MODE_CLOCK);
        builder.setHour(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR));
        builder.setMinute(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        MaterialTimePicker materialTimePicker = builder.build();
        materialTimePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "MATERIAL_TIME_PICKER");
        materialTimePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(v - > {
            Time time = new Time(materialTimePicker.getHour(), materialTimePicker.getMinute(), 0);
            Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("a");

            if (Objects.equals(formatter.format(time), "PM")) {
                int hours = materialTimePicker.getHour() - 12;
                if (hours > 0 && hours <= 9) {
                    if (materialTimePicker.getMinute() <= 9) {
                        timeToNotify = "0" + hours + " : 0" + materialTimePicker.getMinute() + " " + formatter.format(time);
                        binding.timeEditText.setText(timeToNotify);
                    } else {
                        timeToNotify = "0" + hours + " : " + materialTimePicker.getMinute() + " " + formatter.format(time);
                        binding.timeEditText.setText(timeToNotify);
                    }
                } else if (hours > 9) {
                    if (materialTimePicker.getMinute() <= 9) {
                        timeToNotify = hours + " : 0" + materialTimePicker.getMinute() + " " + formatter.format(time);
                        binding.timeEditText.setText(timeToNotify);
                    } else {
                        timeToNotify = hours + " : " + materialTimePicker.getMinute() + " " + formatter.format(time);
                        binding.timeEditText.setText(timeToNotify);
                    }
                } else if (hours == 0) {
                    if (materialTimePicker.getMinute() <= 9) {
                        timeToNotify = "12 : 0" + materialTimePicker.getMinute() + " " + formatter.format(time);
                        binding.timeEditText.setText(timeToNotify);
                    } else {
                        timeToNotify = "12 : " + materialTimePicker.getMinute() + " " + formatter.format(time);
                        binding.timeEditText.setText(timeToNotify);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (materialTimePicker.getHour() > 0 && materialTimePicker.getHour() <= 9) {
                    if (materialTimePicker.getMinute() <= 9) {
                        timeToNotify = "0" + materialTimePicker.getHour() + " : 0" + materialTimePicker.getMinute() + " " + formatter.format(time);
                        binding.timeEditText.setText(timeToNotify);
                    } else {
                        timeToNotify = "0" + materialTimePicker.getHour() + " : " + materialTimePicker.getMinute() + " " + formatter.format(time);
                        binding.timeEditText.setText(timeToNotify);
                    }
                } else if (materialTimePicker.getHour() > 9) {
                    if (materialTimePicker.getMinute() <= 9) {
                        timeToNotify = materialTimePicker.getHour() + " : 0" + materialTimePicker.getMinute() + " " + formatter.format(time);
                        binding.timeEditText.setText(timeToNotify);
                    } else {
                        timeToNotify = materialTimePicker.getHour() + " : " + materialTimePicker.getMinute() + " " + formatter.format(time);
                        binding.timeEditText.setText(timeToNotify);
                    }
                } else if (materialTimePicker.getHour() == 0) {
                    if (materialTimePicker.getMinute() <= 9) {
                        timeToNotify = "12 : 0" + materialTimePicker.getMinute() + " " + formatter.format(time);
                        binding.timeEditText.setText(timeToNotify);
                    } else {
                        timeToNotify = "12 : " + materialTimePicker.getMinute() + " " + formatter.format(time);
                        binding.timeEditText.setText(timeToNotify);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void showMaterialDatePickerToUpdate() {
        MaterialDatePicker.Builder < Long > datePicker = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker();
        datePicker.setTitleText("Select Date...");
        datePicker.setSelection(MaterialDatePicker.todayInUtcMilliseconds());
        datePicker.setInputMode(MaterialDatePicker.INPUT_MODE_CALENDAR);
        MaterialDatePicker < Long > picker = datePicker.build();
        picker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "MATERIAL_DATE_PICKER");
        picker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(selection - > {
            dateToNotify = picker.getHeaderText();
            binding.dateEditText.setText(dateToNotify);
        });
    }
}

BroadCastReceiver.java
public class MyAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm is ON...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```